# NSDictionary allKeys and then sorted with a selector vs keysSortedByValueUsingSelector

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsdictionary

I am trying to get an array of all my keys in my NSDictionary into an array, and sorted using `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`. I first tried doing:

```
NSArray *test = [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

I kept getting `NSCFNumber localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector`. I double checked and all of my 2 keys (for now) are strings.

I had to switch to doing to make it work:

```
NSArray *items = @[[[languages allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

Why is that?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because is `keysSortedBy**Value**UsingSelector` and that's why you get `NSNumber` exception,because is sorting by value , not by key, you have `NSNumbers` as values.

Answer (score 2):

There is different sorting in this two cases.

```
NSArray *test = [myDict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

this variant sort (from docs):

> Returns an array of the dictionary’s keys, in the order they would be in if the dictionary were sorted by its values.

You try to get an array, where you firstly sort values using your selector and then get list of keys. I guess, your dictionary's objects are not `NSString` and they don't know anything about this selector.

```
NSArray *items = @[[[languages allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

Here you do right. You get the array of keys (which are `NSString`) and then sort it using right selector.

Answer (score 0):

`keysSortedby **Value** usingSelector...`